# How to call python from Java serverless function in AWS

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have created a `serverless` function in Java and need to call a python script from this function. I included the script within the zip file and deployed in AWS. When running my function I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I searched a bit and found that AWS has support for Python Lambdas but in my case I need to call a python script from a Java Lambda. Is this supported from AWS or is there any trick I can do ?

Comment: Shelling out from a Lambda JRE to a Python interpreter seems like a very bad idea, even if Python were installed on a Lambda Java container. Why not simply write the Lambda function in Python?

Comment: @jarmod I never used python so it would take me some time to do it like this. On the other hand why is it a bad idea?

Comment: A couple of reasons: event-based serverless solutions should ideally be lightweight; passing data from Java to Python and retrieving responses (and potentially exceptions) in return using some variant of OS exec is not a solution conducive to reliability. But, to the root of your problem, I would guess that the Lambda Java runtime environment simply does not include an installation of Python (or Node or C# or Go).

Comment: You might want to interrogate the Lambda runtime environment from Java just in case Python is actually installed (search the web for "alestic lambdash" for ideas). You might also be able to create a standalone executable from your Python script, host it in S3, and then your Java app could download it, and exec it. I'm not sure how successful this approach would be, but it may be worth investigating. However, if your Java Lambda function is reasonably simple then converting it to Python might also be an option.